# How to find out the PID of the Flinks execution process?

Tags: perf, apache-flink

I want to measure flinks performance with performance counters (perf). My code:

```Scala
var text = env.readTextFile("<filename>")
var counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }.map { (_, 1) }.groupBy(0).sum(1)
counts.writeAsText("<filename_result>", WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
env.execute()
```

I know the PID of the jobmanager. Also I can see the TID of the Thread (CHAIN DataSource), that runs the execute()-command, during execution. But for each execution the TID changes, so it wont work with the TID. Is there a way to figure out the PID of the jobmanagers child process, that runs the execute()-command? And are there different child processes for every transformation (e.g. flatMap) of the rdd? If so, is it possible to find out their distinct PIDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The individual operators are not executed in distinct processes. The `JobManager` and the `TaskManagers` are started as Java processes. The `TaskManager` then runs a set of parallel tasks (corresponding to the operators). Each parallel task is executed in its own thread. When you start Flink, then the system will create files `/tmp/your-name-taskmanager.pid` and `/tmp/your-name-jobmanager.pid` which contain the PID of the processes.

Comment: In the tmp directory only a /tmp/my-name-jobmanager.pid exists and it contains only the PID of the JobManager. How I start Flink: first I start a cluster with /bin/start-cluster.sh (or /bin/start-local.sh) and then I connect a Flink Shell to it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If your `TaskManager` is running on a different machine, then the PID file will be stored on this machine. If you start a local cluster, e.g. using `start-local.sh`, then Flink will only start a single process in which the `JobManager` and a single `TaskManager` runs. If you start the Flink shell without having explicitly started a cluster, then it will start for you a local cluster.

Comment: I start Flink on only one machine, even with start-cluster.sh. So the jobmanager and the taskmanager should be on the same machine, right?

Comment: Yes, you can verify that everything worked by calling `jps`. There you should see a `JobManager` and a `TaskManager` process. If not, then you should look in the `logs/your-hostname-taskmanager.log` file to see what went wrong.

Comment: Ok, now it worked, the taskmanager file in the tmp directory exists. Thanks